# How to get array value in Vue observer?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I have a question about how to take a value of an array when I can not get with Array[i]

I am pushing are response that I got from axios (which are URLS) into an empty array.

And when I console.log the array, it shows value but can not get value by index and length either. For example: this.data[0] ->not working

I also have tried

- Object.keys(data).length
- JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))
- Array.from()

And the picture is what I am getting when I console log

-array it self :console.log(this.pictureData) // you can see what contains in array

-array's length: console.log(this.pictureData.length) // shows me just 0

[image: the picture is what I am getting when I console]

Do you know how can I get a value of a certain key of an array when is showing in an observer?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: probably a *timing* issue since axios, like all AJAX, is asynchronous - console.log evaluates the contents of the array when you view it, therefore, it's not an accurate represenation of when you logged it - i.e. when you log it, it's empty, but when you view it, it's been filled asynchronously - try `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.pictureData))` and you'll see that it's empty, and remains empty in the log (since you've now output the state of the array as an immutable String rather than a mutable Ojbect)

Comment: oh I see, I think you are right. I was so into array, and did not pay attention to axios. I will check my code again. Thanks!